# ASP.NET lock screen in postback (Master Page)

Tags: javascript, c#, css, asp.net, telerik

I am developing ASP.NET Webform application and I want to lock screen in any postback action and showing message like 'Please wait.'. I am able to do it for a control (like Button) event (click event). And I am able to do it from clientclick via javascript. I show a **div** and writing *Please wait* in that div. But I have lots of pages. That means I have to put that div to everypage and I added the code which is showing div to every event function.

I want to do it in Master Page. How can I achieve this goal? My codes are like:

```js
function skm_LockScreen() {
    var lock = document.getElementById('skm_LockPane');
    if (lock)
        lock.className = 'LockOn';
        lock.innerHTML = 'please wait.';
}

function skm_UnLockScreen() {
    var lock = document.getElementById('skm_LockPane');
    if (lock)
        lock.className = 'LockOff';
}
```

```css
.LockOff { 
    display: none; 
    visibility: hidden; 
} 

.LockOn { 
    display: block; 
    visibility: visible; 
    position: absolute; 
    z-index: 999; 
    top: 0px; 
    left: 0px; 
    width: 105%; 
    height: 105%; 
    background-color: #ccc; 
    text-align: center; 
    padding-top: 20%; 
    filter: alpha(opacity=75); 
    opacity: 0.75; 
}
```

```html
<div id="skm_LockPane" class="LockOff"></div>
```

If you have a solution over Telerik, I accept it also. I am using telerik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include your JavaScript and CSS on a MasterPage, and apply on its SlavePages. Like in masterpage.master page put:

```html
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="MyStyles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="MyJavaScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
```

And set id and class on your tag of any page.

Comment: Thanks, I achived as how you explained. Only problem is now in validation summary. It is showed more than one time. But thanks for answer.